# How to replace words in file in bash

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have a file with following content:

```
Blekota blaboli o koblihach.
Blanka je bl...
GEwI
er
```

I need to replace every word starting with `Bl` or `bl` with `xxxx` and save it into new file. I try this, but it did not work.

```sh
while read line; 
do pokus="${line//[Bl|bl].* /xxxx}" 
echo $pokus
done < "$TEXT" > "$TEXT".new
```

Desired output is:

```
xxxx xxxx o koblihach. 
xxxx je xxxx...
GEwI
er
```

What do I do wrong, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using a `sed` command:

```sh
sed 's/\<[Bb]l[[:alpha:]]*/xxxx/g' file

xxxx xxxx o koblihach.
xxxx je xxxx...
GEwI
er
```

Here `\<[Bb]l[[:alpha:]]*` matches a word starting with `Bl` or `bl` followed by 0 or more alphabets.

Answer (score 3):

***1st solution:*** Using `gsub` function of `awk` to substitute all fields which are starting from `Bl` OR `bl` then it will assign it to `xxxx`.

```
awk '{gsub(/(^[Bb]l|\<[Bb]l)[^[:space:]]+/,"xxxx")} 1' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With `awk` you could try following. Simple explanation would be traversing through each field of each line and then checking condition if it starts with `Bl` OR `bl` then assign it to `xxxx` and then print edited/non-edited line.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^[Bb]l/){$i="xxxx"}}} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: I think you could shorten the first awk to using the word boundary only, as there is also a word boundary between `B` or `b` and the start of the string. `awk '{gsub(/\<[Bb]l[^[:space:]]+/,"xxxx")} 1' file`